# How to use unicode character as field separator in mysql LOAD DATA INFILE query

Tags: mysql, unicode

I'm trying to import a file into a MySql database using query below. The fields in the file are delimited by '¦' (broken vertical bar) U+00A6.
I'm executing the query from PhpMyAdmin

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/path/filename.csv" INTO TABLE tablename 
CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '¦'
```

Somehow mysql ignores the field separator and loads all records into the first field of the table

Comment: I was able to reproduce your problem with a file created and saved using Sublime without any encoding. And then after opening and saving in TextEdit on Mac, my answer below worked. Also make sure the entire table is set to utf-8 Unicode, not just the rows. Saving in Sublime as UTF-8 also worked.

Answer (score 0):

The source document is probably encoded in unwanted characters, such as what Excel does. Try opening and saving in TextEdit, or another bare bones text editor, making sure the data is saved as UTF-8. Then:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "filepath/file.csv" INTO TABLE `table`
CHARACTER SET 'utf8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\¦';
```

With escape character before broken bar. Also use UTF-8 Unicode encoding on the entire table, not just the rows.

Comment: This would work for sure that being said replacing the delimiter on a 25MB file on daily basis would be too inefficient

Comment: Does the data have non-English characters? It works without the utf8 line: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "filepath/doc.csv" INTO TABLE `table`
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '¦';

Comment: When I LOAD it without the UTF8 it recognizes the delimiter and the query loads the data into the correct fields of the table however it places "Â" gibrish character at the end of every sting in varchar type fields

Comment: Did you try backslash before broken bar '\¦' ? See edit to my answer.

Comment: I did ... didn't work it dumps all the content into the first field.

Comment: Provide a sample set of your data.

Comment: `¦` mojibaked becomes `Â¦`.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent it like `X'A6'`

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/path/filename.csv" INTO TABLE tablename 
CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY X'A6'
```

Comment: I tried it...unfortunately it didn't work,   could it be because I'm executing the query from PhpMyAdmin ?

Comment: Not sure absolutely. Try running from MySQL command prompt. Also, try using `X'01'` as field terminator.

Comment: X'01' represents the first unicode character not the broken vertical bar so it would not work

Comment: @HenryJava, only work around I see is then, transforming your source file to replace the string. fastest way of doing that would be using `sed/awk`

Comment: `A6` is the hex for the _latin1_ encoding for `¦`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NAMES utf8;   -- You were probably missing this (or the equivalent)
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "/path/filename.csv" INTO TABLE tablename 
    CHARACTER SET 'UTF8'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '¦'
```

(assuming you can type ¦ in utf8, not latin1)

The clue was `"Â" gibrish character at the end of every sting`, together with `¦` mojibaked becomes `Â¦`.

Comment: The problem is typing the '¦' in utf 8 in PHPmyadmin.  this is not easy. I'm wondering how is it even possible that such a simple task is almost impossible to acomplish. I'm not thrilled with MySQL

Comment: You need to "type" it only once, for the `LOAD DATA`.  At that time, you can copy & paste from this page.  There are several competing products; feel free to switch to some product you will be thrilled with.

Comment: I did and it didn't work I also copied the character from charmap program that didn't work either

Comment: Copy it from a listing of the .csv file.  Could we see a sample of that file?